# Get size of a database that is hosted on a linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Does anyone know how to get the size of a dabase that is hosted on a different server? I basicly want to monitor the size of that DB in a Job on my server.
I tried something like:

```
select db_name(dbid), str(convert(dec(15),sum(size))* 8192/ 1048576,10) 
from [LINKEDSERVER].master.sys.sysaltfiles 
group by dbid order by 2 desc
```

For some reason this gives me the data on my current server instead of the remote server.
Also, I've read on a forum that the sysaltfiles is only updated at server restarts? This would make it unusable for monitoring, so do you have a better option instead?

Comment: sp_spaceused  I don't have a linked server to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one , it works i checked

```
EXEC ('SELECT d.name,
ROUND(SUM(mf.size) * 8 / 1024, 0) Size_MBs
FROM sys.master_files mf
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4 
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY d.name') AT [LINKEDSERVER]
```

Comment: i get Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Server 'LINKEDSERVER' is not configured for RPC.

Comment: Ok, set the RPC out to true on the linked server and now it work. Thanks!